# Using Func with instance method

Tags: c#

```
public class x : y
{    

public Func<user, bool> SendStuffAction = SendStuff;

//overridden from y
public override bool SendStuff(user u)
{
  //do stuff
}

}
```

Taking the above code, where SendStuff is an local overridden instance method, I get a context error that SendStuff not being static. Can't a delegate point to an instance method from inside the same class to which the method SendStuff exists?

Error is:cannot access static method in a non-static context

What if the method is private, why would it not work then.

```
private Func<user, bool> SendStuffAction = SendStuff;
```

Comment: post more code. this piece looks fine

Comment: can anyone explain why SendStuffAction is treated as being static?

Comment: If you use a method as a field initializer, it always has to be a static method.  There's no way to guarantee the instance is in a consistent state before the fields are initialized, so instance methods aren't allowed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it can...but, you need to set it in the constructor if you do not declare as static.

```
class MyClass
{
   public Func<loan, user, bool> SendStuffAction ;

   MyClass()
   {
      SendStuffAction = SendStuff;
   }

   bool SendStuff(loan loanVar, user userVar)
   {
      return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but can you explain a little more as to why this is?

Comment: [+1 interesting, hadn't realised this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923343/c-error-class-delegate-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-non-static).  As Toby mentions in the main question's comments above, using a non-static member in a field initialiser opens it to being used elsewhere while the instance being constructed is in an unknown state (initialisers execute in unknown order).  You're allowed to do it in the constructor, because field initialisers have finished and you have control over the order of any remaining initialisation, though you still have to be careful.