# In C#, how to forbid user from setting my reference property

Tags: c#, properties, reference, reference-type

Honestly,I know I can miss the set clause to avoid user setting my property.
Like below code:

```
private Dictionary<int, string> _configurations = new Dictionary<TState, StateConfiguration>();

public Dictionary<int, string> Configurations { get { return _configurations; } }
```

So, we can't run below code at outer code:

```
XXX.Configurations = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

It prompts :

```
Property or indexer 'XXX.Configurations' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

But we can change the value like below code:

```
XXX.Configurations.Add(1,"1000")
```

Because dictionary is a reference type.

So how can I avoid this. Let user access the reference property with no changing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a read-only generic dictionary available in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678379/is-there-a-read-only-generic-dictionary-available-in-net)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to expose a collection property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35007/how-to-expose-a-collection-property)

Answer (score 3):

You could try returning the dictionary as [read-only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712981(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public IDictionary<int, string> Configurations 
{ 
  get { return new ReadOnlyDictionary(_configurations); } 
}
```

Comment: ReadOnlyDictionary does not inherit from Dictionary

Comment: Personally, I would recommend returning an [IReadonlyDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh136548.aspx).  I'm not a fan of treating `ReadOnlyDictionary`; I find `IDictionary` to be a bit dangerous, since it throws an exception on modification rather than outright disallowing it; too much code ignores the the `IsReadOnly` property.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to expose a [`ReadOnlyDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875). You *could* create a new one each time the property is accessed, or you could have two fields - one for the writable dictionary (which you never expose) and one for the read-only wrapper.